# How to view a Georgian language string in a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, georgian

If a TextView has a georgian text, I see only spaces.

i.e

```
String georgString = "("+"სახლი ქუჩის ბოლოში"+")";
```

I see:

```
"(        )"
```

Answer (score 0):

> If a TextView has a georgian text, I see only spaces.

I found quick solution. You need to add your gregorian text into `strings.xml` and then it will work.

```
<string name="test">(სახლი ქუჩის ბოლოში)</string>

// an usage
textView.setText(getString(R.string.test));
```

<sub>(**I just tested it** and **it works**. Probably if you are assigning text directly there is problem with encoding but with an usage of resources you don't have to deal with it). Let me know.</sub>

Comment: thank 4 suggestion. But, if the value arrives from a DB dinamically, and is not a constant? (as in my case...). Ps: Android 2.3.3